# Compilation error using enum in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, enums, visual-studio-2019

I defined this `enum` inside my class:

```
enum MenuNavigation : int {
    FileMenu,
    AutoAssign,
    EditMenu,
    ViewMenu,
    OptionsMenu,
    HelpMenu
};
```

When I compiled it I received a compilation error:

> ```
> 5>D:\My Programs\2019\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\CreateReportDlg.h(360,7):
>   error C2365: 'CCreateReportDlg::AutoAssign': redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
>
> 5>D:\My Programs\2019\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\CreateReportDlg.h(190):
>   message : see declaration of 'CCreateReportDlg::AutoAssign'
> ```

On line 360 I have a function declaration:

```
BOOL AutoAssign(UINT uNumToFill, 
                UINT uStartIndex, 
                CStringArray &rAryStrAllBrothers, ROW_DATA_S &rsRowData, int iGridColumn);
```

If I rename my enumerator item as `AutoAssignments` or `kAutoAssign` it compiles.

I don't understand why a `enum` value which I understood has scope can't have the same name as a function defined in the parent class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand why a `enum` value which I understood has scope can't have the same name as a function defined in the parent class?

This is not true. `enum`s with members having the same name will clash.

What you should use instead is [scoped enumerations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), e.g.:

```
enum class MenuNavigation : int {
    FileMenu,
    AutoAssign,
    EditMenu,
    ViewMenu,
    OptionsMenu,
    HelpMenu
};
```

and then `MenuNavigation::AutoAssign`.

You should do the same thing for `CCreateReportDlg`, and then `CCreateReportDlg::AutoAssign` and `MenuNavigation::AutoAssign` would never clash.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that. Using `class` does indeed resolve the issue!

Comment: I had another couple of `enums` in the dialog class so I thought I would use `class` with them but my project would not compile. Some of my functions expect `int` values. I would have to cast. Pity one has to do that when we have stated the `enum` is of type `int`. Anyway, I don't get that issue for the initial enumeration, so thanks.

Comment: If/when you have the time, consider making those enums scoped as well, and explicitly casting when needed. Avoiding accidental conversions might be worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why a enum value which I understood has scope can't
>   have the same name as a function defined in the parent class?

The enumerator that you have defined is *unscoped*, so its members' scope will be that of the surrounding module or namespace.

To define a *scoped* enumerator, add `class` to the declaration; then its members will only be visible with the class prefix:

```cpp
enum class MenuNavigation : int {
    FileMenu,
    AutoAssign, // We can now use this name without a clash in the function...
    EditMenu,   // ... use MenuNavigation::AutoAssign to refer to the value!
    ViewMenu,
    OptionsMenu,
    HelpMenu
};

BOOL AutoAssign(UINT uNumToFill,
    UINT uStartIndex,
    CStringArray& rAryStrAllBrothers, ROW_DATA_S& rsRowData, int iGridColumn);
```

Further reading on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).